# How to download a file from a url in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, url

What's the best way to download a file from a given url? There are times when the url is not the actual url of the file but a "follow to" url which takes us to a file or sometimes a video player is present on the link that plays the video.

How can we ensure the download of the file from those links? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want is the [`request` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or it's promise-based version the [`request-promise` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

The request library will follow 3xx redirects by default, assuming that's what you meant by "follow to" url.

If the link takes you to a web page that contains a video player, what the request library in node.js will download is the web page, not all the other resources referenced in the web page.  If you want to download a specific resource used in the web page, then you have to download the web page, parse it with a tool such as [`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio), find the link to the resource you actually want in that web page and then download that specific resource using its URL.

As always with questions here on stack overflow, the more you explain about the eventual final result you're trying to achieve, the better we can help you here.  Based on what you've disclosed in the question so far, I think I've answered what you asked, but it feels like there's probably more to the real question than what you've shown so far.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Does Request library all follows the redirects when making a Head request?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash - I don't know for sure,  but if the response is a 3xx status, I would think it probably does.  Either study the doc and code or run a simple experiment to try.